# Flutter - Changing Deployment Target

Tags: flutter, simulator, podfile

I have downloaded a project on the Internet and cannot run it. I've searched the solution but could not solve it. I'm a new Macbook user and don't know much about it (Podfiles etc.). Here is the error that I'm getting:

> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Runner' from
> project 'Runner')
> warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID.
> To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in
> target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

I have tried to change the target deployment on Flutter.podspec file but every time when I run the code, it goes back to 8.0[image]

Comment: Open runner inside your xcode and after that navigate to the general tab and change the deployment target to your desired number. By default its 8. Then close your Xcode and try to build again, it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find where the Runner is. I'm working on VS Code, should I make the changes on Xcode or the Simulator?

Comment: For anyone who may find this question in the future, there are .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace files in the ios folder in VSCode. Editing the deployment target there did me no good, because a later build changed it back. I couldn't remove my upvote because it was too late. I had another unrelated issue.